# In a multisite, how can I get posts from one site and display their permalinks in another site?

Tags: permalinks, multisite, get-posts

I have a WordPress multisite with one main site and four sub-sites.  In a PHP template on my main site, I would like to get the posts from one of the sub-sites and print the permalinks to the page.  How is this done?

My code is below--when this code is executed, permalinks are indeed printed to the screen, but they are incorrect--the post name is correct, but the path is incorrect.

```
$tp_blog_id = 4;
switch_to_blog( $tp_blog_id );
$posts = get_posts(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'property',
                'posts_per_page' => 100,
                'numberposts' => -1
            )
);
restore_current_blog();
error_log(print_r($posts,true));
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo "The URL is: <br>";    
    echo get_blog_permalink( $tp_blog_id, $post->ID ) . "<br>";
}
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQuVb.jpg) of the output page.  The permalinks incorrect--each of those leads to a 404 page.  The incorrect permalinks printed in this case are of the form

`http://dev.thailandproperty-hh.com/pattaya/blog/property/1-bedroom-condo-central-pattaya-10/`

when in actuality the permalinks are

`http://dev.thailandproperty-hh.com/pattaya/property/1-bedroom-condo-central-pattaya-10/.`

As a test, to my error log, I printed the contents of the `$posts` array.  It does indeed contain all the desired post objects.  In addition, each post object in the array has a property `guid`, the value of which is the correct permalink ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76cub.jpg)).  I guess as a workaround I could simply echo this property to the page, instead of `get_blog_permalink()`.  But I'd like to understand why the latter is not returning the expected permalink.

**UPDATE**

I register my CPT using code below:

```
$slug = get_theme_mod( 'property_permalink' );
$slug = ( empty( $slug ) ) ? 'property' : $slug;
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => $slug ),
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'menu_position'       => null,
        'supports'            => $supports,
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'property_type' )
    );

register_post_type( 'property', $args );
```

Comment: And how do you register that CPT?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż is is registered in this manner:  https://pastebin.com/Lb4DdRbz

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at `get_blog_permalink`:

```
get_blog_permalink( $blog_id, $post_id ) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    $link = get_permalink( $post_id );
    restore_current_blog();

    return $link;
}
```

As you can see, there's no magic... But there are some problems, since `switch_to_blog` isn't very efficient...

It means that it would be way better if you'd done it this way:

```
$tp_blog_id = 4;
switch_to_blog( $tp_blog_id );
$posts = get_posts(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'property',
                'posts_per_page' => 100,
                'numberposts' => -1
            )
);

error_log( print_r($posts,true) );
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo "The URL is: <br>";    
    echo get_permalink( $post->ID ) . "<br>";
}
restore_current_blog();
```

And if the problem with permalinks still occur, then you'll have to check the way you register this CPT (especially the `with_front` part of `rewrite` param in `register_post_type`).

And as I expected, the problem lies exactly in that spot. When you register your CPT you use:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $slug ),
```

If you'll take a look at [`register_post_type` docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite), then you'll see that this param has multiple fields:

> - `slug` => string Customize the permalink structure slug. Defaults to
>     the $post_type value. Should be translatable.
> - `with_front` => bool
>     Should the permalink structure be prepended with the front base.
>     (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then your links will
>     be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to true
> - `feeds` => bool Should a feed permalink structure be built for this post type. Defaults to has_archive value.
> - `pages` => bool Should the permalink
>     structure provide for pagination. Defaults to true
> - `ep_mask` => const
>     As of 3.4 Assign an endpoint mask for this post type. For more info
>     see Rewrite API/add_rewrite_endpoint, and Make WordPress Plugins
>     summary of endpoints. If not specified, then it inherits from
>     permalink_epmask(if permalink_epmask is set), otherwise defaults to
>     EP_PERMALINK.

As you can see one of them is `with_front` and its default value is `true`. That means that your post type is told to prepend front base to its URLs.

So if the front base is set to blog, then the URL for that post type shuld contain it - so it's generated correctly...

PS. It's hard to say why it causes 404 errors and how exactly are these links processed, so it works without front base. But your problem is clear - there is something wrong with registering and processing that CPT.

Comment: I tried your method, and the same issue occurred:  incorrect permalinks.  You mentioned that at this point, I should check the way I register this custom post type.  I checked, and for this CPT, `register_post_type()` is called in this manner:  https://pastebin.com/Lb4DdRbz  Are you saying that something about the `rewrite` parameter may be incorrect?

Comment: @cag8f I've updated my answer.

Comment: OK I understand.  I also see that my main site has a front base set to `post` and the sub-site in-question has a front base set to `pattaya`.  That seems to in-part be consistent with what you've described (although I don't understand why the `blog` is added after the `pattaya` in my case, and I don't see where the `property` portion of the permalink is added).

Comment: But going back to my original question--what would be the proper way to print the correct permalinks in this case?  Is there any simple way to grab that value from a post object (or somewhere else)?  Or would I have to manually modify the permalink string, i.e. remove the `blog` in my case?